# Fix the inconsistency in revision numbering

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list

It appears that revisions are indexed starting both at 0 and 1 (related, [sometimes they just don't make sense at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88511)).

For example, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs) says "9 revs, 8 users".  But in [the revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9953/revisions), the most recent revision is numbered 10 not 9.  That 10th revision is also a reversion, to revision 8 (the summary is automatically generated).

The original post was not a revision of itself, obviously, so 0-indexing and "9 revisions" makes sense.  But it was the first *version*, so 1-indexing and "10 versions" makes sense as well.  But I think we should have something consistent so we all know what we're talking about.

**Solution 1:** Have the revisions page start the numbering at 0, or have the original post marked "OP" and the revisions to it start as 1.  (The auto-generated text on a reversion would follow suit.)  This is my preferred solution, since it makes the numbers consistent between *versions* and *revisions*.

**Solution 2:** Change the text on the posts from "X revs" to "ver. Y".  The example question would then show "ver. 10, 8 users" rather than "9 revs, 8 users".  I prefer "revs" though, and hence prefer the first proposal.

Comment: Does 0/1-indexing have anything to do with it? It just seems like this is a bug, particularly with the one that has 97 revisions but says 103 -- is it 7-indexed?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Community Wiki revision counter missing one revision](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88511). This was reported earlier in [Revision count incorrect on CW question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26384), but that question was deleted, for whatever reason. (By the way, I love your 103-97 example!)

Comment: @Michael I think it might be due to being migrated from SO.  Hendrik, thanks for finding the dupe.  I'll leave this to be purely about the 0/1 indexing and update that other question with the 103-97 example.

Comment: @Hendrik Completed :)

Comment: @Matthew: I've never thought about this "revision counter" problem in this way - maybe you have a point here. I always thought the original post was counted as "revision 1" (although it's not revisited yet).